# 2.How to edit/update records from the database using textbox by linq to sql?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit/update records from the database using textbox by linq to sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565161/how-to-edit-update-records-from-the-database-using-textbox-by-linq-to-sql)

I'm using visual basic 2008 express edition by linq to sql for my database operation such as edit records. I did not use any sql server but I'm just using the built-in sql server within the visual basic 2008 express. I tried to revised the codes, no error in syntax but there's an error at runtime and it pops-up a window message saying its error message. What I want is to edit the records which were retrieved from the database into the text-boxes and when you click the button5 whatever the new value on the text-boxes should replace the previous one.
The **Account** field is the field in my Table1 in memrec.dbml which I set up for primary key is true and the rest of the fields are false in its primary key.
The code below still found an error when you run the program and it pops-up a window which says:

**NotSupportedException was unhandled** - Sql server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.

It highlights a yellow background on the line:

```
db.SubmitChanges()
```

These are what I see on each field's property on Table1 in memrec.dbml property window:

```
Access - Public
Type - String(System.String)
Server Data Type - Text
Auto-Generated Value - False
Auto-Sync - Never
Delay Loaded - False
Nullable - True
Read Only - False
Time Stamp - False
Update Check - Never
Primary Key - False ' Except for the Account field.
```

What do you see as possible error?

Is it in terms of its settings?

Here's my code:

---

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(------------------) Handles Button5.Click 
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or _
            TextBox4.Text   = "" Then 
        MsgBox("Please Fill It Up Completely", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation) 
        Exit Sub 
    Else 

        Dim accnt As String 
            accnt = TextBox1.Text 
        Dim db As New memrecDataContext() 

        Dim editrecord = _ 
            From memrec In db.Table1s _ 
            Where memrec.Account.Contains(accnt) _ 
            Select memrec 

        For Each memrec In editrecord 
            If memrec.Account = accnt Then 

                memrec.Account = TextBox1.Text 
                memrec.Name = TextBox2.Text  
                memrec.Address = TextBox3.Text 
                memrec.Gender = TextBox4.Text 
                db.SubmitChanges() 
                Exit Sub 
            End If 
        Exit For 

        Next 

        MsgBox("No Records Match", MsgBoxStyle.Information) 
    End If 
End Sub
```

---

Thank you for taking time with me to solve this issue.....